# My webpage seems to work on certain platforms and not on others, the css doesn't get applied, why is this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a link to my webpage https://taniaswebpages.com/, specifically Website 5 - Snowfall that I am currently working on, the webpage only works for me on Safari on Iphone6s, and doesn't apply the css on Mac Chrome/Safari. But for others it works... why is it changing depending on the type of platform or user?

HTML/CSS:

```css
body.mainpage2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: lato;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.color {
  margin-top: 350px;
  text-align: center;
}

#hex {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.color button {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 6px 30px 5px #fff;
  width: 200px;
}

body.mainpage3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(221, 106, 95, 0.81));
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em 2em 4em;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 16.5px;
  line-height: 24px;
  float;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: block;
}

input[type=button] {
  width: 8%;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: palevioletred;
}

.image1 {
  position: relative;
  right: -400px;
  bottom: 600px;
  animation: shake 0.9s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.image2 {
  position: relative;
  right: -100px;
  bottom: 200px;
  animation: shake 0.9s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}

body.mainpage4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.container1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

.container1 span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}

.Words1 {
  color: forestgreen;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.Words2 {
  color: red;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 750;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  animation: blinkingText 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText {
  0% {
    color: #f00;
  }
  49% {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: transparent;
  }
  99% {
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    color: #f00;
  }
}

.image {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.snow1 {
  background: url(https://taniaswebpages.com/snow.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: snowfall 3s infinite linear;
}

.snow2 {
  background: url(snow.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: snowfall 8s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes snowfall {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100px 650px
  }
}

@keyframes snowfallSecond {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px -100px
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 650px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="taniaWebsite2.css" type=text/css rel=Stylesheet>
</head>

<body class="mainpage4">
  <div class="container1">
    <span class="Words1">Merry Christmas</span>
    <span class="Words2"> and Happy Holidays!</span>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <div class="snow1"></div>
    <div class="snow2"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this worked fine for me in Internet Explorer and Chrome on PC and Safari on iOS. The only thing I saw was that on mobile, the image doesn't go 100% of the page height and so the snowflakes stop at about halfway down the page. This can be fixed through CSS.

Comment: "on another phone" .. which phone? Android/IOS/? The phone spec will tell you the dimensions, and so guide you to which media query needs work..

Comment: what can I do to make the snowflakes be on the entire page. I've made the height 100%?. And sometimes when I click the webpage link through Instagram, it shows me a white page (ios). @rachelGallen can you be more specific as to what I need to add/change to my css? I would really appreciate it, as im just learning.

Comment: @tsharma I was asking what type of phone it was .. A HTC One? Samsung Galaxy? iPhone 7? Look up the screensize of the phone and then you'll know what size needs work

Comment: @rachelgallen, ive gotten the snowflake to extend to the bottom of my screen. But for some reason the webpage does not open as it should on Chrome on Mac. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: @tsharma no I do not as "not as it should" is a very vague description of a problem.

Comment: @rachelGallen, What I meant to say is that when I open my webpage on Chrome Mac, all I can see is blank text & the css is not applied. Whereas on my Iphone 6s, I can see it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<link href="taniaWebsite2.css" type=text/css rel=Stylesheet>
```

to

```
<link href="taniaWebsite2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

With quotes around the attribute values and all lowercase.

Comment: Agree with this; the only thing the validator picked up was the lack of a title in the head section.